# Jsoup is unable to extract login html contents for me

Tags: jsoup

[image]I am running into a problem where in I need to extract DOM html for login window for website **https://webuy.com**
I tried with below code to get the scraping done for login but could not get success:

```
Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).timeout(0).get();
        System.out.println(document.toString());
     Element textField = document.getElementsByClass("login-form"); 
or Element textField = loginDoc.select("div").first();
```

*I dont get html contents of login window rather I get the html contents behind the login modal.*
Please someone suggest me what could be the solution to it.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to get the dynamic html content:

```
  WebElement elem = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*"));
    String html = elem.getAttribute("innerHTML");

readPropertiesFile(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/src/dynamicObjectRepo/OR.properties");
        writePropertiesFile(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/src/dynamicObjectRepo/OR.properties", locatorAction ,html);
    // custom file to write the html content to properties fie
public static Properties writePropertiesFile(String fileName, String variableLocator, String genericXpath) throws IOException {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
        try {
            prop.setProperty(variableLocator, genericXpath);
            prop.store(out, null);
            out.close();
        } catch(FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
            fnfe.printStackTrace();
        } catch(IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            out.close();
        }
        return prop;
    }
Now i have got the whole html content of the page which includes login form contents as well. I can extract now the textfield by using jsoup methods.
```